# Autotools: include python script in ./configure.sh

Tags: python, linux, configure, autotools, autoconf

Building of our Linux C application is performed by GNU Autotools, and during the one we need to look through client's file system and construct quite complex configurational files. From our point of view, Python scripting is the best way to solve this problem.

1. So, is it possible to run custom python script inside
   **./configure.sh**?
2. How should the **configure.ac** and **Makefile.am** files be changed for this purpose?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm kind of assuming **configure.sh** is `configure`.

1. Sure. `configure` is just a shell script.
2. automake has facilities for [Python](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Python.html#Python), the [Autoconf Macro Archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/The-Macros.html) has some Python macros also.